# Why are two of my checkbox values not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm not sure why these two checkbox's are not working. (children and overall). Am I missing something here. starRating and adults works. I have put it into a sandbox and also included the code at the bottom.

Essentially it should be filtering via checkbox. Currently it filters via rating and adults but not by children or overall guests. It's actually stuck on the checked value. I'm sure it's something simple.

Any advice would be really helpful.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [hotelRooms, setHotelRooms] = useState([]);
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState({ ratings: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"] });
  const [extra, setExtra] = useState({ occupancy: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"] });
    const [kids, setKids] = useState({ stay: ["1","2"] });
    const [overall, setOverall] = useState({ total: ["1","2", "3", "4", "5"] });
  const fetchHotels = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(
      "https://obmng.dbm.guestline.net/api/hotels?collection-id=OBMNG"
    );
    const hotels = await res.json();

    const hotelRooms = [];

    for (const hotel of hotels) {
      const res = await fetch(
        `https://obmng.dbm.guestline.net/api/roomRates/OBMNG/${hotel.id}`
      );
      const info = await res.json();
      hotelRooms.push({ hotel, rooms: info.rooms });
    }

    setHotelRooms(hotelRooms);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchHotels();
  }, []);

  const handleRatingFilter = (e) => {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      // adding value
      const temp = [...filter.ratings];
      temp.push(e.target.value);
      setFilter({ ...filter, ratings: temp });
    } else {
      // removing value
      setFilter({
        ...filter,
        ratings: [...filter.ratings.filter((v) => v !== e.target.value)]
      });
    }
  };

  const handleGuestsOverall = (e) => {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      // adding value
      const people = [...overall.total];
      people.push(e.target.value);
      setOverall({ ...overall, total: people });
    } else {
      // removing value
      setOverall({
        ...overall,
       total: [...overall.total.filter((i) => i !== e.target.value)]
      });
    }
  };

  const handleOccupancyExtra = (e) => {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      const perm = [...extra.occupancy];
      perm.push(e.target.value);
      setExtra({ ...extra, occupancy: perm });
    } else {
      setExtra({
        ...extra,
        occupancy: [...extra.occupancy.filter((d) => d !== e.target.value)]
      });
    }
  };

  const handleKidsStay = (e) => {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      const children = [...kids.stay];
      children.push(e.target.value);
      setKids({ ...kids, stay: children });
    } else {
      setKids({
        ...kids,
        stay: [...kids.stay.filter((g) => g !== e.target.value)]
      });
    }
  };


  console.log(hotelRooms);
  console.log(extra);
  console.log(kids)
  console.log(overall)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        {["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"].map((star) => (
          <div key={"input-" + star}>
            <input
              id={"rated" + star}
              value={star}
              name="ratings"
              type="checkbox"
              checked={filter.ratings.includes(star)}
              onChange={handleRatingFilter}
            />
            <label htmlFor={"rated" + star}>Rated {star} star</label>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div>
        {["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"].map((adults) => (
          <div key={"adults" + adults}>
            <input
              id={"maximum" + adults}
              value={adults}
              name="extra"
              type="checkbox"
              checked={extra.occupancy.includes(adults)}
              onChange={handleOccupancyExtra}
            />
            <label htmlFor={"maximum" + adults}>adults {adults}</label>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>

      <div>
        {["1", "2"].map((kiddies) => (
          <div key={"children" + kiddies}>
            <input
              id={"children" + kiddies}
              value={kiddies}
              name="children"
              type="checkbox"
              checked={kids.stay.includes(kiddies)}
              onChange={handleKidsStay}
            />
            <label htmlFor={"children" + kiddies}>Children {kiddies}</label>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>

      <div>
        {["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"].map((people) => (
          <div key={"ppl" + people}>
            <input
              id={"people" + people}
              value={people}
              name="people"
              type="checkbox"
              checked={overall.total.includes(people)}
              onChange={handleGuestsOverall}
            />
            <label htmlFor={"people" + people}>Overall Guests {people}</label>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>

      {hotelRooms
        .filter(
          (h) =>
            filter.ratings.includes(h.hotel.starRating) &&
            h.rooms.some((room) =>
              extra.occupancy.includes(room.occupancy.maxAdults + room.occupancy.maxChildren + "")
            )
        )
        .map((h, idx) => (
          <div key={idx}>
            <h2> Name: {h.hotel.name}</h2>
            <p> Description: {h.hotel.description}</p>
            <p> Rating: {h.hotel.starRating}</p>
            <p> Postcode: {h.hotel.postcode}</p>
            <p> City: {h.hotel.town}</p>

            <p style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>Rooms:</p>

            {h.rooms
              .filter((room) =>
                extra.occupancy.includes(room.occupancy.maxAdults + room.occupancy.maxChildren + "")
              )
              .map((room, idx) => (
                <div key={idx}>
                  <h5>Occupancy</h5>

                  <div> adults: {room.occupancy.maxAdults}</div>
                  <div> Children: {room.occupancy.maxChildren}</div>
                  <div> Maximum guests: {room.occupancy.maxOverall}</div>
                  <div> Room type: {room.name}</div>
                </div>
              ))}
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Small tip: in order to help people help you, please do some effort to reduce the code to the really-needed length.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I was afraid of leaving something out. I wanted to avoid someone commenting saying where is that function where is this etc....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to use stay: instead of kids here

```
setKids({
    ...kids,
    stay: [...kids.stay.filter((g) => g !== e.target.value)]
  });
```

And total here

```
setOverall({
    ...overall,
    total: [...overall.total.filter((i) => i !== e.target.value)]
  });
```

For the filtering problem maybe replace the h.rooms.filter with this

```
h.rooms.filter((room) => (
  extra.occupancy.includes(room.occupancy.maxAdults.toString())&& 
  kids.stay.includes(room.occupancy.maxChildren.toString()) && 
  overall.total.includes(room.occupancy.maxOverall.toString())
))
```

Comment: Yes, I just changed that, thanks for spotting that. But now, it won't filter for any. Not sure what's going on

Comment: I edited my answer with a possible solution

Comment: yes that worked ! why did toString solve it ? and why can i not follow the same logic and add another like this       {h.rooms.filter((room) => (
            extra.occupancy.includes(room.occupancy.maxAdults.toString()) && 
            kids.stay.includes(room.occupancy.maxChildren.toString()) &&
            overall.total.includes(room.occupancymaxOverall.toString())
    ))

Comment: the filter with overAll seems to work for me, i edited the answer with my changes. The toString() solves it because in the room property from hotelrooms, the values are numbers so you have to convert it to string before comparing them with your state ones.

Comment: yes it works now, so strange. Thank you so much!!!